# UITableView not updating as picker turned

Tags: iphone, uitableview, sdk, picker

I want a user to spin a picker and as a specific row appears, it should load an appropriate array and display it in a UITableView.  I would prefer it if the user did *not* have to spin the picker and then press a separate "select" button.

I have the usual picker and table methods, but the table won't update as the picker is spun.  The table does update on the initial NIB load, but nothing thereafter.

This is the picker method.  The arrays are loaded and reloadData is called , but then nothing...?

Help appreciated.

```
(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

NSLog(@"Selected: %@. Index: %i", [pickerSelections objectAtIndex:row], row);

pickerChoice = [pickerSelections objectAtIndex:row];

if (pickerChoice==@"String1"){

    NSLog(@"load Array1");

    Names1 = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Bob Jones",@"Joe Brown",@"Nigel Smith",nil];

    [contactTable reloadData];

}else if (pickerChoice==@"String2"){

    NSLog(@"load Array2");

    Names2 = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Bob Jennings",@"Joe Brown",@"Nigel Smith",nil];

    [contactTable reloadData];

}

}
```

Comment: Are you sure the contactTable's IBOutlet is connected properly in IB?  Also, you should use isEqualToString: instead of ==.

Comment: Can you post the code for the cellforrowatindexpath of the table view's data source?

Answer (score 0):

Groan - my bad.  I triple checked everything and then noticed I had forgotten to add "IBOutlet" in the @property for the table and picker.  What was I thinking.  Once added, I was able to connect in IB (of course) and everything fire up just fine.